# How to export Unity to Android Studio with ARM v8 support?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I tried setting IL2CPP as the builder and exporting but it only exports the x86 and ARM v7 native libs. Is it possible to export a Unity 5.3 project as an Android Studio project with ARM v8 jni libs bundled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible for export a Unity project for ARMv8 on Android now. This is something that will be added in the future, but we're not sure when yet. For now, only 32-bit is supported.

Comment: Expanding a bit: Unity does not provide armv8 native libraries at the moment, that's why they don't get exported :)

Comment: Is it not possible even with the new IL2CPP compiler?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, as IL2CPP generates C++ code that can be compiled for any architecture. However, there are a number of other considerations. ARMv8 will likely be supported for Android at some point though.